# Duplicate Users listed in Azure Synapse Workspace

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-synapse

Using SQL Server Management Studio I have created a SQL User in my Synapse serverless database using the following syntax

CREATE USER [app-myappnameadsgsdaga-uat-westus] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER

(This is an Azure AD application)

After creating the user I see the login listed in SSMS under security/users:
[image: database user in SSMS]

When I browse the same database using Synapse Studio, I see the user listed multiple times:
[image: database user in Synapse Studio]

Is this a bug in Synapse Studio, or am I creating the user in the wrong way?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. That is just idle conjecture though. MS may appreciate it if you raise it.. somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try refreshing databases in Synapse Studio and/or workspace? 
 
If that didn't help, please create a support ticket. You can do this by navigating to feedback and then click on "Contact support" where you will have an option to add the description of your issue.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I tried refreshing but that doesn't' fix it. Its not really causing any issues for me so I don't need support. I was just curious if I was doing something wrong or its an existing UI bug.